# What is the parameterized complexity of following model checking problem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, descriptive-complexity, parameterized-complexity, finite-model-theory, model-checking

---

Input: Graph $G$ and formula $\varphi_1(\vec x),\varphi_2(\vec x)$

Parameter: $tw(G)+|\varphi_1|+|\varphi_2|$

Problem: Decide if $|\varphi_1(G)|=|\varphi_2(G)|$

---

where $tw(G)$ is the treewidth of $G$ and $\varphi(G):=\{\vec a|(G,\vec a)\models\varphi\}$.

What is the parametrized complexity of this problem for $\varphi_i\in FO$ or $\varphi_i\in MSO$?

Comment: What is tw(G) ?

Comment: @Sylvain: maybe the treewidth of a graph?

Comment: @Sylvain: Sorry, I added the explanation.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the meaning of "the absolute value of a formula applied to a graph" : $\vert \varphi_{1}(G)\vert$ ?

Comment: I guess it is the number of good assignments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is $\mathsf{FPT}$ for $\varphi_i \in MSO$ (and hence also for $\varphi_i \in FO$).

More precisely, Courcelle *et al.* prove in [1] the following:

> **Theorem [1, Thm. 32]**
>   Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a class of graphs which is of bounded tree-width $k$.
>   Then any $MSO_2$ definable counting problem, given by $\varphi$, can be solved in time $c_k \cdot \mathcal{O}(|V| + |E|)$, where $c_k$ is a constant which depends only on $\varphi$ and $k$.

$MSO_2$ stands for monadic second-order logic where the universe is $V \cup E$ (vertices and edges), and we are given a binary relation $R(v,e)$ for the incidence between a vertex $u$ and an edge $e$. This is a quite natural representation of graphs, sufficiently powerful to *e.g.* define Hamiltonicity.

[1]: [B.Courcelle, J.A.Makowsky, U.Rotics. On the fixed parameter complexity of graph enumeration problems definable in monadic second-order logic. Discrete Applied Mathematics 108, pp. 23-52 (2001)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X%2800%2900221-3)

Comment: I am not sure, if I remember well this paper is about bounded tree width structure, which is not the case here.

Comment: In this paper (and usually in parameterized complexity), "bounded _measure_" means "as parameter". I should precise that **Theorem 32** in this paper precisely states that any $MSO_2$ formula $\varphi$ can be decided on an input graph $G$ in $\mathcal{O}\big(f(tw(G),\varphi) \cdot |G|\big)$ time.

Comment: So, my mistake then, sorry.